# Saving Generated CSV to Server in Proper format as download

Tags: php, html, csv, save

I've have been successful in exporting my database to csv as a downloadable file. However what I now need to do is instead of creating a straight .csv file that's downloaded I need it to just save to a folder called "csv" on the server. Here is my code for the current export. I need help in the saving it to server. I'm not saving the data correctly.

```
    // output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('tax_class_id','_product_websites'));

// fetch the data
mysql_connect('localhost:3036', 'x', 'x');
mysql_select_db('lato');
$rows = mysql_query('SELECT taxclass,productwebsite FROM product');

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) 
fputcsv($output, $row);

$filename = "data.csv"; // Trying to save file in server
file_put_contents("download/" . $filename, "$header\n$rows");
```

Comment: Duplicate Question from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166207/database-to-csvdone-trying-to-save-file-to-folder-on-server/17208956#17208956

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your last line to

```
$filename = "data.csv"; // Trying to save file in server
file_put_contents("download/" . $filename, $output);
```